# InstallShield 2010 change title of the choose setup language dialog

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010

I've inherited an InstallShield project and need to change the title of the setup language dialog. It is currently the same as every other dialog in the installer `[Product name] - InstallShield Wizard`. I've found the string I need in the localisation ini file, but cannot find the dialog anywhere inside the project, nor any options around the releases/build options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `IFX_SETUP_TITLE` to set only the Product Title.
If you have a custom dialog make sure you have resource id set to `50` or `51`. If there is no resource ID with the value of `50` or `51`, even using `IFX_SETUP_TITLE` will not change title name.